# homology with integral coefficients vs homology with field coefficients

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Suppose that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous mapping between connected topological spaces such that for any field $k$, $H_{\ast}(X,k)\rightarrow H_{\ast}(Y,k)$ is an isomorphism. Does it follow that $H_{\ast}(X,\mathbf{Z})\rightarrow H_{\ast}(Y,\mathbf{Z})$ is an isomorphism in integral homolgy ? Do we need to assume that $X$ and $Y$ are simply connected ?

Comment: I think the universal coefficient theorem implies it has to be surjective.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit: Please be aware that the current answer mistakenly assumes $\mathbb{Z}/p^\infty$ is a colimit rather than a limit of $\mathbb{Z}/p^n$ and so is wrong in its current form. The correct approach would be to argue that the mapping cone is acyclic using  Corollary 3A.7 of Hatcher.

Edit 2: Upon further investigation, it was originally correct $\mathbb{Z}/p^\infty$ is written as a filtered colimit. Let me try to find a specific flaw with the rest of the argument. I believe the potentially suspicious implication that this proof demonstrates is that a homology isomorphism with coefficients in all $\mathbb{Z}/p^k$ implies a homology isomorphism with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/p^\infty$. Here is an elaboration on this part of the argument where it becomes clear where the false assumption is.

Suppose $C \rightarrow C'$ is a chain map such that $H_*(C;\mathbb{Z}/p^k) \rightarrow H_*(C';\mathbb{Z}/p^k)$ induces isomorphisms in homology. By definition this means that $H_*(C \otimes \mathbb{Z}/p^k) \xrightarrow{\cong} H_*(C' \otimes \mathbb{Z}/p^k)$. If we take a colimit we have $\mathrm{colim}_k H_*(C \otimes \mathbb{Z}/p^k) \xrightarrow{\cong} \mathrm{colim}_k H_*(C' \otimes \mathbb{Z}/p^k)$ since levelwise the map of diagrams is an isomorphism. Homology commutes with filtered colimits, so we have $H_*(\mathrm{colim}_k (C \otimes \mathbb{Z}/p^k)) \xrightarrow{\cong} H_*(\mathrm{colim}_k (C' \otimes \mathbb{Z}/p^k))$. Colimits commute with tensor products, so we have $H_*(C \otimes \mathrm{colim}_k ( \mathbb{Z}/p^k)) \xrightarrow{\cong} H_*(C' \otimes \mathrm{colim}_k (\mathbb{Z}/p^k))$. By the colimit definition of $\mathbb{Z}/p^\infty$ this is $H_*(C \otimes  \mathbb{Z}/p^\infty) \xrightarrow{\cong} H_*(C' \otimes \mathbb{Z}/p^\infty)$ which is $H_*(C ; \mathbb{Z}/p^\infty) \xrightarrow{\cong} H_*(C' ; \mathbb{Z}/p^\infty)$, as stated.

It seems to me the error is "Colimits commute with tensor products, so we have $H_*(C \otimes \mathrm{colim}_k ( \mathbb{Z}/p^k)) \xrightarrow{\cong} H_*(C' \otimes \mathrm{colim}_k (\mathbb{Z}/p^k))$". Of course, colimits commute with tensoring by the same chain complex, not quasiisomorphic ones. This is where Tor comes in as suggested by Dave.

---

In fact, you only need it for $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/p$. There is a very useful short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \oplus _p \mathbb{Z}/p^\infty \rightarrow 0$. In this case, it gives us a long exact sequence in homology $ \dots \rightarrow H_{n+1} (X;\oplus _p \mathbb{Z}/p^\infty) \rightarrow H_n(X; \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow H_n(X; \mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow H_n(X;\oplus _p \mathbb{Z}/p^\infty) \rightarrow \dots$ . If we knew that an isomorphism with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/p$ gave rise to an isomorphism with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/p ^\infty$ we would be done by the five lemma. So let's prove that it does.

For all $k$ we have a short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p^{k-1} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p^k \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p \rightarrow 0$, so by induction, the long exact sequence on homology coming from this short exact sequence, and the five lemma we have that the induced map on homology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/p^m$ is an isomorphism for all $m$. Now we want to show that the homology with coefficients in $\lim\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{Z}/p^k=\mathbb{Z}/p^\infty$ is the same as the colimit of the homology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/p^k$. This follows directly from the fact that on the chain complex level the colimit of the $C_n(X ; \mathbb{Z}/p^k)$ is $C_n(X ; \lim\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{Z}/p^k)$ and that taking homology commutes with direct limits. So we have an isomorphism on homology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/p^\infty$. Direct summing over all $p$ we can then apply the five lemma to the initial long exact sequence, and we are done.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! The proof in Hatcher is to show that if an abelian group $A$ satisfies $\mathbb{Q}\otimes A=0$ and $\mathop{\rm Tor}(\mathbb{Z}/p,A)=0$ then $A=0$. You do need $\mathop{\rm Tor}$ somewhere because $A=\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ has the property that its tensor with any additive group of a field is zero.

Comment: Just to have a link, the issue mentioned in the introduction is fixed in your [MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/451420).

Comment: @DaveBenson I think I have located the specific error; thanks for all the help.